# PDF header and footer laravel snappy

Tags: laravel, pdf, snappy

I have a problem with including footer in laravel snappy

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('sales.sale_form1', [
            'sale' => $sale, 'items' => $items, 'client' => $client,
        ])->setOption('footer-html', route('pdf.footer'));
```

I use this code but it does not include the footer

Comment: $headerHtml = view()->make('sales.header')->render();
        $footerHtml = view()->make('sales.footer')->render();
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('sales.sale_form1', [
            'sale' => $sale, 'items' => $items, 'client' => $client
        ])->setOption('footer-html', $footerHtml);

I used this method too

Comment: put code in the post/question